# Round the value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have scenario where if user enters for example `000.03`, I want to show the user it as `.03` instead of `000.03`. How can I do this with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
function showRounded(val) {
    var zero = parseInt(val.split('.')[0],10) === 0;
    return zero ? val.substring(val.indexOf('.')) : val.replace(/^0+/,'') );
}
console.log(showRounded('000.03')); //=> ".03"
console.log(showRounded('900.03')); //=> "900.03"
console.log(showRounded('009.03')); //=> "9.03"
```

Or adjust Álvaro G. Vicario's solution to get rid of leading zero's into:

```
String(parseFloat("090.03")).replace(/^0+\./, ".")
```

Comment: "00000.03" -> ".03"; "999.03" -> ".03"

Comment: You’re missing a few closing brackets, check the `console.log()` statements.

Answer (score 2):

This actually is trickier than it first seems. Removing leading zero's is not something that is standard Javascript. I found this elegant solution online and edited it a bit.

```
function removeLeadingZeros(strNumber)
{
  while (strNumber.substr(0,1) == '0' && strNumber.length>1)
  {
    strNumber = strNumber.substr(1);
  }
  return strNumber;
}

userInput = "000.03";
alert(removeLeadingZeros(userInput));
```

Comment: `var1 = 000.03;` will fail as it's not a valid number in JS.

Comment: It's worth nothing that `toPrecision()` is a method of `Number`. It won't apply directly to entered values which are always strings. Also, you still need to remove leading zeros.

Comment: @Box9: good point!, @Vicario: you're also right, I'll modify my post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression:

```
"000.03".replace(/^0+\./, ".");
```

Adjust it to your liking.

Comment: `"020.03".replace(/^0+\./, ".");`; I know it's not the question, though it should be handled the same, right?

Comment: @andre matos Yep, the specs don't really mention this case ;-)

Comment: And you always go by the specs, even when they are senseless? :) I wish I could always do that too! eheh

Answer (score 1):

This function will take any string and try to parse it as a number, then format it the way you described:

```
function makePretty(userInput) {
  var num,
      str;
  num = parseFloat(userInput); // e.g. 0.03
  str = userInput.toString();
  if (!isNaN(num) && str.substring(0, 1) === '0') {
    str = str.substring(1); // e.g. .03
  } else if (isNaN(num)) {
    str = userInput; // it’s not a number, so just return the input
  }
  return str;
}

makePretty('000.03'); // '.03'
makePretty('020.03'); // '20.03'
```

It you feed it something it cannot parse as a number, it will just return it back.

**Update:** Oh, I see If the single leading zero needs to be removed as well. Updated the code.

Comment: That won't remove leading zeros.

Comment: To downvoter: please add a comment explaining the reason. While it doesn't answer the precise question, I don't think it qualifies as "Not useful".

Comment: @Álvaro: Good point, I’ve now updated my post. My solution will also work for stuff like `"020.03"` :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input's all the same format, and you want to display the `.`

```
user = "000.03";
user = user.substring(3);
```

Comment: how unfair! poor user / person.. ok. use a regex and don't do it on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a string into a number and back into a string to format it as `"0.03"`:

```
var input = "000.03";
var output = (+input).toString(); // "0.03"
```

To get rid of any leading zeroes (e.g. ".03"), you can do:

```
var input = "000.03";
var output = input.substr(input.indexOf(".")); // ".03"
```

However, this improperly strips "20.30" to ".30". You can combine the first two methods to get around this:

```
var input = "000.03";
var output = Math.abs(+input) < 1 ?
    input.substr(input.indexOf(".")) :
    (+"000.03").toString();
```

Comment: Since it’s user input, you should really use `parseFloat`. E.g. `+"000.03 foo"` returns `NaN`, but `parseFloat("000.03 foo")` will correctly return `0.03`.

Comment: I think that really depends on what you want. One is stricter than the other. even parsefloat will fail if the input is foo000.03